# Blender python script to select an existing geometry nodes group

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

Very noob question here, I am probably missing something and can't get my code to work properly. I want to create a new object, cube or whatever, add a Geometry nodes modifier to it and select from a drop down menu an existing, 'Fake user' group named 'Mygroup'. This last part is not working properly, I cannot get it to select that group even though if I go manually I can see it and select it normally.
Most recently I tried answers from [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259867/geometry-nodes-as-mesh-generation-script) and modified it to correct name but id doesn't work. I am using Blender 3.31 and as I write 3.4.

My code looks like this:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='NODES')
bpy.data.node_groups['Mygroup']
```

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on what exactly doesn't work ? It throws an error ?

Comment: So just that last part, after creating an object and adding a geometry nodes modifier I cannot get it to select an existing node group from the drop down list.

Comment: It doesnt create an error, it just doesnt sellect a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to have a `Node group` already in the scene.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.context.object.modifiers.new('geometry','NODES')
bpy.context.object.modifiers['geometry'].node_group = bpy.data.node_groups['Mygroup']
```

Comment: That's it, solved! I get it. Thank you Muzammil.